# Set Index in computed function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, computed-properties

I have a v-for loop like following:

```
<div class="inputArea mt-2" v-for="(id, index) in inputs" :key="index">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 m-1">
      <div class="mt-2">Input Number</div>
      <b-form-input type="number" v-model="Number[index]"></b-form-input>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 ml-1 mr-1">
        <div class="mt-2">Autofill 1</div>
        <b-form-input type="text" :value="Autofill[index].autofill1" </b-form-input>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 ml-1 mr-1">
        <div class="mt-2">Autofill 2</div>
        <b-form-input type="text" :value="Autofill[index].autofill2" </b-form-input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I reference my index into a computed function:

```
 computed: {
    Autofill() {      <!-- Autofill[index]() is not working -->
        var returnelement = {};
        if(this.json!= undefined) {
          this.json.forEach(element => {
            for(const item of this.Number) {
              if (+element.number === +item) 
              returnelement = element;
            }
          }); 
        }
        return returnelement;
      }, 
  },

 data() {
      return {
        inputs:[{}],
        Number: [],
        json: json, //imported before
      }
  }
```

Autofill[index] ( ) is not working, but I need this unique index in here..

Thanks for helping me out!

[image]

Comment: Can you show where you are using `Autofill` in your template?

Comment: Added it to the code ! Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: Can you print an example of the output of `Autofill`?

Comment: Added a picture how it looks right now - I have multiply elements but in each element there will be the same autofill inputs. But I need seperate inputs for each element.

Comment: But if I have Autofill[Index].autofill1 and also with autofill2 in my template it didn't work - but I need these unique indexes to reference it to my Autofill

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

If you want to pass the index from the loop to Autofill, then you should use the methods.
You cannot pass data to a function from computed.

```html
<div class="inputArea mt-2" v-for="(id, index) in inputs" :key="index">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 m-1">
      <div class="mt-2">Number</div>
      <b-form-input type="number" v-model="Number[index]"></b-form-input>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 ml-1 mr-1">
        <div class="mt-2">Autofill 1</div>
        <b-form-input type="text" :value="Autofill(index).autofill1" </b-form-input>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 ml-1 mr-1">
        <div class="mt-2">Autofill 2</div>
        <b-form-input type="text" :value="Autofill(index).autofill2" </b-form-input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
export default {
  //...
  methods: {
    Autofill(index) {
      var returnelement = {};
      if (this.json != undefined) {
        this.json.forEach(element => {
          for (const item of index) {
            if (+element.number === +item)
              returnelement = element;
          }
        });
      }
      return returnelement;
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: If I try this my autofill is not working anymore.. I can input my numbers but it will not autofill the other to fields..

Comment: @patrick96 Сreate an example in codesandbox.io along with all the data you are using, json should be there too.
In your example, it is not clear what you want to achieve with your code.